# Why does Django remove translations from django.po when using gettext inside f-strings

Tags: python, django, gettext

For some weird reason, Django removes the translations from `django.po` file, if I used `gettext` or `gettext_lazy` inside Formatted String Literals (F-Strings)!

ex:

```
from django.contrib.admin import admin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class fooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def bar(self, foo):
        return format_html(f'''{_("Variable")}: {value1}<br />''')
```

When I update the messages by `python manage.py makemessages --all --symlinks` Django removes the `Variable` from `django.po` translation file, as long as `Variable` is not being used anywhere else except in the code above!

Why is that?